# R: rotated raster is cropped when terra:rectify() is applied

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff

I have a geotiff that I read with
`rastertif <- terra::rast(x = tif)`
This produces the following warning:

```
[rast] the data in this file are rotated. Use 'rectify' to fix that
```

So I use rectify like this:

```
rastertif1 <- terra::rectify(rastertif)
```

This rotates the raster, but the rectangle is cropped - see the following plot:
[image: plot of rotated raster]

The plot should show a completed rotated rectangle, but some parts on top and on the right hand side are cropped.

Any idea how the raster could be rotated while keeping the full extent?

Comment: I can't find a rotated raster and the help for rectify doesn't generate one for an example. Can you point us to one?

Comment: Here is one: https://www.filemail.com/d/zerzradizidtoim

Answer (score 0):

I manually enlarged the bounding box of the SpatRaster like this:

```
e <- terra::ext(rastertif)
e$xmax <- e$xmax + 3000
e$ymax <- e$ymax + 3000

ext(rastertif) <- e

rastertif1 <- terra::rectify(rastertif, aoi = e)
```

Now, my raster is not cropped anymore after rectifying:
[image: rotated raster, not cropped]

Comment: However, the transformation is extremely slow.